# C# Get last Array Element

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I has the following collection in my collection:

```
{
    "Target_Year" : 2017,
    "Target_Month" : 6,
    "Performance" : [ 
       {
        "Report_Day": 1,
        "First_Level_Superior" : "WS66"
    }, 
    {
        "Report_Day": 2,
        "First_Level_Superior" : "CN4"
    }
},
{
    "Target_Year" : 2017,
    "Target_Month" : 7,
    "Performance" : [ 
       {
        "Report_Day": 10,
        "First_Level_Superior" : "WS66"
    }, 
    {
        "Report_Day": 11,
        "First_Level_Superior" : "CN4"
    }
}
```

I has the codes to retrieve all Performance.

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filterMain = builder.Eq("Target_Year", "2017")
var project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Performance.$");
var result = mongoDB.Performance.Find(filterMain).Project(project).ToList();
```

How can I retrieve the max Report_Day sub document for each document instead of all documents?

Comment: Sorry but I have to note that I keep correcting the formatting on your posts. Can you please actually look at how the formatting is correctly done and follow it in all future posts.

Comment: Ok. noted on that. Thanks for the reminder.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) here to get the "last" which is the "latest" or "max":

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filterMain = builder.Eq("Target_Year", "2017")
var project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Slice("Performance",-1);
var result = mongoDB.Performance.Find(filterMain).Project(project).ToList();
```